# Refactoring old jsp site

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I'm refactoring old jsp site when *.jsp has embedded java code. Cos logic is large I dont want change strongly technology, just want run it on tomcat again introducing beans, jstl. I have ~ 10 kind of html templates with constant part. I found pattern for my refactoring: One jsp with master layout plus about 10 sections with module html and configured beans `<jstl:when test="<%=siteBean.getModule()==SiteModules.index%>">` and configured beans inside sections eg.

```
<jsp:useBean id="editPlayerBean" class="EditPlayerBean"/>
                <%
                    editPlayerBean.setSiteBean(siteBean);
                %>
```

Is it good concept for refactoring that site from performance - economical criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's a good approach re-factoring a site this way.

Try to remove all the script-lets and use expression language rather. 
Save your beans in suitable scope and use them using EL.
Transform all your conditions into equivalent JSTL tags.
Your HTML parts will remain same.

After integrating with JSTL, your code will be more readable and easier to maintain. Go for it.